# Excel VBA: Using .Cells() to dynamically reference cell in cell formula

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range, formula

I want to create a cell formula which references cells like B1, e.g. `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=B1*" & x`. However, I want to use the `.Cells` function rather than a `Range` reference to reference cells.

Given:

```
Dim x As Integer 
Dim y As Integer 
x = 5
y = 10
```

I want this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(y,1) & "*" & x
```

To provide the same output as:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=B" & y & "*" & x
```

Ideally, I want to be able to dynamically change both the row and column of the cell I am referencing in the formula. However, I still want the cell to show up as a cell in the formula and not simply the value of the referenced cell.

Comment: What's the problem you're coming across?

Comment: You can get the address of a cell rather than its formula by using `.Address` - e.g., `ActiveSheet.Cells(y,1).Address(False, False)`.

Comment: Okay, I see how `.Address` works in regards to avoiding getting a formula, but if I use `.Address`, will this: `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(y,1).Address(False, False)` give me the same as this:  `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=B" & y & "*" & x`, provided x = 5 and y = 10?

Comment: ^After testing it out, it seems to work!

Comment: @rdhs How do you set `ActiveSheet.Cells(y,1).Address(False, False)` equal to a variable. What object type is it?  A range? (I tried to set it to a range and it did not work)

Comment: @rdhs +1 Sweet, tbh, your comment answered this question as far as I'm concerned

Answer (score 0):

If I see that correctly then your problem is that you want map the cell numbers to their cell names; similar to this:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,x).Formula = "=" & Chr(Ord("A") + 1) & y & "*" & x
```

Keep in mind that this will only work for the first 26 columns, after that you'll need to find a better solution.